# Extending a class and one of its properites

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

There is this class design issue that I keep running into over and over and I've come to realize that I must be doing something wrong.  The idea is that class B : A.  These classes using configuration objects and BConfig : AConfig.  The issue is that I can't come up with a good way to make the properties in BConfig accessible.

Here's an simplified example of the issue.

```
public class Request{

  public virtual RequestConfiguration Config{
   get
   {
     if(Config == null)
       Config= ConfigurationManager.GetSection("RequestConfig")
              as RequestConfiguration;
     return Config;
   }
  }

  public virtual string DoSomething(){
    return "Url:" + Config.Url;
  }

}

public class AuthRequest : Request
{
   public override RequestConfiguration Config
   get
   {
     if(Config == null)
       Config= ConfigurationManager.GetSection("RequestConfig")
              as AuthRequestConfiguration;
     return Config;
   }
  }

  public override string DoSomething(){
    return String.Format("Url:{0} U:{1} P:{2}",Config.Url,Config.User,Config.Pass);
  }
}

/*---- Configuration Classes ----*/
public class RequestConfiguration : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("RequestHost", IsRequired = true)]
    public string RequestHost
    {
        get { return (string)base["RequestHost"]; }
    }
}    
public class AuthRequestConfiguration : RequestConfiguration
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("User", IsRequired = true)]
    public string User
    {
        get { return (string)base["User"]; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("Pass", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Pass
    {
        get { return (string)base["Pass"]; }
    }
}
```

Obviously this code doesn't compile.  **Is there any small changes to this code that could be made to achieve the same principle?**  Or do I need to take a whole different approach all together?

The goal is that I can use simple dependency injection set up in a configuration file to determine what type of request to make.

Comment: In a word no. I'd like to point you in an excat direction, but I'm really struggling to see the intent. DI is done through aggregation (interfaces) not inheritance, so AConfig and BConfig should be implementations of IConfig, then your expose problem goes away, maybe. Essentially as soon as you reach for inheritance when doing DI, treat the desire to do so, with extreme suspicion.

Comment: I realized that a bit after posting this question.  Refactored both classes to inherit from a abstract IRequest Class.  The area I'm having problems is that there is boiler plate code that all inheriting classes need that uses the base RequestConfiguration (why I made it an abstract class instead of a Interface).

Comment: Can you delegate it  to an other class instance even oh the horror of it a static helper class. So instead of being a thingie they have a thingie.

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson:  I ended up creating a Abstract Generic Class that implements the solution provided by Kristian Hellang that both the Request and AuthRequest Inherit from.  It might not be the best design but for my purpose it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about making `Request` generic; `Request<TConfig> where TConfig : RequestConfiguration`:

```cs
public class Request<TConfig> where TConfig : RequestConfiguration
{
    private TConfig _config;

    public virtual TConfig Config
    {
        get { return _config ?? (_config = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("RequestConfig") as TConfig); }
    }

    public virtual string DoSomething()
    {
        return "Url:" + Config.Url;
    }
}

public class AuthRequest : Request<AuthRequestConfiguration>
{
    public override string DoSomething()
    {
        return String.Format("Url:{0} U:{1} P:{2}", Config.Url, Config.User, Config.Pass);
    }
}

public class RequestConfiguration : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Url", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Url
    {
        get { return (string) this["Url"]; }
    }
}

public class AuthRequestConfiguration : RequestConfiguration
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("User", IsRequired = true)]
    public string User
    {
        get { return (string) this["User"]; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("Pass", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Pass
    {
        get { return (string) this["Pass"]; }
    }
}
```

Would that solve your problem? At least the code builds :)

Comment: nice...  play around with that idea monday.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the properties are declared on RequestConfiguration and AuthRequestConfiguration.

For example,  if you declare the Url property as virtual in the RequestConfiguration class and  declare it as an override in the AuthRequestConfiguration class,  it should do what you are expecting.

Detailed example from MSDN is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4(v=vs.80).aspx